# Proof that $\overline{X-A}={X-A^o}$

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification

I have to prove that $\overline{X-A}={X-A^o}$ where $A^o$ are all the inner points of A.
I will start with $\overline{X-A}$ According to my book that means $\overline{X-A}$ $<=>$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ that
$B(x,\varepsilon)\cap(X-A)\neq\emptyset$
How do i continue with this proof?

Ps $B(x,ε)$ is a ball in X

Comment: Take any $ p\in X-A^o$ and then show that $p\in \overline {(X-A)}$. Note that $p$ is not an interior point of $A$ and repeat the argument in other direction.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $X$ is the entire metric space. Since $\mathrm{Int}A \subseteq A$ it follows that $X\setminus A \subseteq X\setminus \mathrm{Int}A$, but the latter is closed, therefore
$$ \mathrm{Cl}(X\setminus A) \subseteq \mathrm{Cl}(X\setminus \mathrm{Int}A) = X\setminus \mathrm{Int}A. $$
Conversely, take $x\in X\setminus \mathrm{Int}A$. Since it is NOT an interior point, it means for every $\varepsilon >0$ the set $B(x,\varepsilon) \cap X\setminus A$ is non-empty, which is what you're after.